# trying to delete a file upload from the database

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to delete the 'avatar' property from the user's database. this is not working. what should be done?

auth is the middleware function that has access to current user.

```
router.delete('/users/profile/avatar', auth, async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
       delete req.user.avatar
       console.log(req.user.avatar)
      await req.user.save()
      res.status(200).send('photo deleted.')
  }
     catch (e) {
         res.status(500).send()
    }
```

})

Comment: Which Database are you using?

Comment: I'm using mongodb with mongoose.

Comment: when i consoled "req.user.avatar" its printing the  buffer which i added in the user's schema.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to find the User on which you want to remove the avatar field, best way would be by `_id`. I'm assuming you can get `id` of the user

```
User.updateOne({ _id: req.user.id }, { $unset: { avatar: 1 } }, (err, user) => {
if (err) {
    res.status(500)
}
  res.status(200).send('photo deleted.')
})
```